# Populate NSTableView with unknown number of columns

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableview and a button. NSTableview has a unknown number of columns.

The first column has a image well and 2 text boxes, the others (again, unknown number) are normal textbox columns.

The button opens up a file open dialogue. Once I choose the files (.jpg) I would like to process them.

So far everything is made (chose files, columns, etc..) what is missing is the populating of the table:

I have the loop that goes through all the selected files. What is the best way to do this:

- display the image in the image well of the first cell,
- type the filename in the first textbox of the  first cell,
- type the filepath in the second cell of the textbox,
- type "YES" in all other columns.

My difficulty is that I have no idea how many columns will be there since it depends from the user. The number of columns will not change during Runtime. they are set up at startup based on the configuration. if the configuration is changed then the app should be reloaded.

I am a beginner in Objective-C/Cocoa programming.

EDIT:
additional info as requested:

It is a view based NSTableView
each column represents an action that has to be taken in a later moment on an image. the program user can decide what and how many actions to take, thats the reason for a unknown amount of columns in the table view.

Comment: A table view is regular, all rows must have the same number of columns.

Comment: thanks, all rows DO have the same number of columns. but i do not know how many since the user can add how many he wants.. so i cannot create a model without knowing the number of elements it will have...

Comment: Nice question, if the difference between the minimum/ maximum amount of columns that the table view might have is very low, you can consider creating multiple views, each one contains a different table view (depending on the number of columns), and swap the views when you need to change the number of columns.

Comment: unfortunately it can be anything from 2 to 40 columns...

Comment: Does the item in each row represent a .jpg file in the file system? And you're saying that, similar to how the Finder allows you to choose which columns you want in list view (Date Modified, Kind, etc.), you are allowing the user to choose which columns they want shown in your table? If so, what are the purposes of the different columns? Is this a view-based `NSTableView`, or cell-based?

Comment: There should be no need to force the user to relaunch the app just because you change what columns they want shown. (In fact, if I tried an app that did that, it would quickly end up in the Trash). You can easily add or remove table columns dynamically and then call `[tableView reloadData]` to have the new columns filled out correctly. But it would help to know more about the purposes of the different columns.

Comment: the application makes use of core data and for each entry in the database there is a column in this table. basically these images are processed afterwards, and each image should be processed for each of the database entries. so in the first column i have the image informations, and in the other columns i have the list of things that should be done with this image. (one per column) the user can decide how many things should be done with this image.

Comment: sorry didnt see your question: its a viewbased table

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add columns programmatically using `addTableColumn:`. This method takes an `NSTableColumn` instance that you can create in your code.

The rest of your architecture (displaying images, etc.) does not particularly change from "normal" code just because the columns have been added dynamically.

Here is a snippet that should get you started:

```
NSTableColumn* tc          = [[NSTableColumn alloc] init];

NSString *columnIdentifier = @"NewCol"; // Make a distinct one for each column
NSString *columnHeader     = @"New Column"; // Or whatever you want to show the user

[[tc headerCell ] setStringValue: columnHeader];
tc.identifier = columnIdentifier;

// You may need this one, too, to get it to show.
self.dataTableview.headerView.needsDisplay = YES;
```

When populating the table, and assuming that the model is an array (in `self.model`) of `NSDictionary` objects, it could go something like this;

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{

     NSString *columnIdentifier = tableColumn.identifier;

     NSDictionary *rowDict = [self.model objectAtIndex: row];

     NSString *value = [rowDict valueForKey: columnIdentifier]; // Presuming the value is stored as a string 
     
     // Show the value in the view
}
```

More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview).

Comment: thanks but that part is already done! my problem is populating the  table!

Comment: @user2035269 - ah sorry, but how is that different from populating a normal table created with Interface Builder?

Comment: thats the question.. :) how can i set up a model if i do not know how many columns there are? i have no idea on how i could fill up the table like i described above.. if it would be as easy then id probably have downvotes and and an answer.. :) but i am a beginner and maybe i just didnt explain myself properly.. any help appreciated! thanks

Comment: @user2035269 Ah, I see. Just use `NSDictionary`'s (or the mutable ones) and identify each column by a string as the key. Use the same string as you used for the column identifier in the table view. But this is turning out to be more of a problem of dynamic data structures that table views. Maybe you should post a new question?

Comment: nah, dont want to post a new question as this would remain unanswered. thanks for your suggestion! could you post it as answer please so i can accpet it if it works? maybe if possible with a small example would be even better!

Comment: also please keep in mind that i am working with images, so it must be compatible with it..

Comment: @user2035269 Added a bit about who to deal with a dynamic model, but please split this rather wieldy question up into sub-questions, such as how to show images in a table view.

Answer (score 2):

When user adds a column or row, you should reflect it in your model (by binding or by code), so you know the size of your table, when you need to populating it.

set tableView.delegate (in code or in Interface Builder),  reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDelegate)

implement:

```
- (NSView*) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{ 
    Item* itemView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"rowItem" owner:self];

    /*Here you populate your cell view*/
    id entryObject = [self.entries objectAtIndex:row];
    [itemView setEntry:entryObject];

    return itemView;
}
```

and then invoke `[tableView reloadData];`

maybe for you better to use this method

`- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex`

Just see the [NSTableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004178) and [NSTableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDelegate)